# Permission denied (publickey). Why deploy doesn'r work?

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket, cicd

Good day!

During the deploy process, an error appears: "Permission denied (publickey)". The matter is that in "Access Keys" of my repository I added a public key `rsa`. But unfortunately the deployment doesn't work.

#error

```
  ○ fetching updates
  ○ full fetch
Permission denied (publickey).
  fetch failed
Deploy failed
```

when I write the command `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` on my server, everything is fine

```sh
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

result:

```sh
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

but no deployment process occurs. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the output of `git remote -v` show `git@bitbucket.org`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no(
`# git remote -v` 

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: May you run the command in the git repo (on the server)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox same answer

Comment: So you guarantee that the server has the correct ssh key, and that running `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` on the server says it's authenticated.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` say `authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled`

Comment: And does the deploy process use this key?